# running administration point

Tags: module, administration, point, opencms

i am working on new modul for OpenCMS. In /system/workplace/admin i made directory and set up all properties well because in administration, i can see my new modul - i see icon of module, also i can click on it and enter in to new module.

Here is my problem: in administration, i have not see output of index.jsp. When i run index.jsp alone i see right output in but not in administration.

I also se up variable default-file=index.jsp

anybody know what i need to set up for right running?

thanks all :)